# Select list not working in firewatir

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, watir, firewatir

i am using firewatir on firefox 3.0.10

But when i write the script

@browser.select_list(:id, "edit-profile-ecs-orgtype").set("Training institute")

this code is working but nothing appears on the screen that is "Training institute" is not selected and no failure is there.

But the same script runs with Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 1):

I would try using

```
@browser.select_list(:id, "edit-profile-ecs-orgtype").select("Training institute")
```

Although when I ran into the issue it was actually the other way around, and Firewatir was much more forgiving than Watir.